# .PivotTables function not recognized in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

VBA seems to ignore the .PivotTables function in the code below.  Does anybody have any possible explanation for this?  Could there be a necessary but inactive reference library? Thanks in advance.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlConsolidation, SourceData:= 
_"Raw!" & 
Sheets("Raw").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1),  
Version:=6).CreatePivotTable _
tabledestination:="PivotTable!" & Sheets("PivotTable").Range("A" & 
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 3).Address _
(ReferenceStyle:=R1C1), TableName:="MFTPiv1", defaultversion:=6

With ActiveSheet.pivottables("MFTPiv1").PivotFields("Wholesaler")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With
```

Comment: At the point that `With ActiveSheet.pivottables("MFTPiv1").PivotFields("Wholesaler")` is firing, is the sheet "PivotTable" active?

Comment: Can you elaborate further about what you are trying to do? For instanec, can you comment on why you are using a SourceType of xlConsolidation (so that we know whether this is intentional, or accidental). Also, that first bit of code really should be broken down into separate bits for readability. First, set up a range variable for the destination range. Then create the PivotCache. Then create a PivotTable based on that cache in the destination range. Mashing everything together like you are doing impedes the ability to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

If your sheet isn't active it can't be found by "ActiveSheet".  Make your sheet "PivotTable" active:

```
Sheets("PivotTable").Select
With ActiveSheet.pivottables("MFTPiv1").PivotFields("Wholesaler")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
  .Position = 1
End With
```

Or not:

```
With Sheets("PivotTable").pivottables("MFTPiv1").PivotFields("Wholesaler")
  .Orientation = xlRowField
  .Position = 1
End With
```

Additionally, I've never used that "xlConsolidation" source type.  I tried it on a bit of data I have here and it created a pivot table that is not conducive to what you're trying to accomplish.  A "standard" pivot cache uses SourceType:=xlDatabase.  Maybe try that.

Comment: I do activate the sheet "PivotTable" just prior to the pivotcache creation lines.  I have added an additional line to activate the "PivotTable" sheet prior to customizing the pivot tables to no avail.  The PivotTables function does not seem to be recognized, as indicated by the fact that VBA does not allow the P in Pivot or T in tables to be capitalized..

Comment: What happens when you use F8 to step through the code?  Does it just skip over that portion or does it stop the code there?  Is "Wholesaler" field available in the pivot table?  There aren't any spaces in the names such as "PivotTable " or "Wholesaler "?

Comment: Updated my answer to try SourceType:=xlDatabase

Comment: The lack of capitalisation is because Excel doesn't know until the code runs whether the activesheet is a normal sheet, or a chart sheet. So intellisense doesn't work, and the word pivottables doesn't get automatically capitalized. But that in itself has nothing to do with your problem.